# how to keep a track of background process run by system() in C Linux?

Tags: c, node.js, linux

I am starting a node application in the background from my C application. However, I want to keep a track whether the node is running or not. Like, I want to keep monitoring whether the node is running or not. If it isn't then I want to start it.

How to do this and is there any way to get a pid of the node while running in the background from the system() call? Also, any API to know whether the node is running or not? 
Here is my system API.

*

```
int nodeCmd (const char *command)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* This is the child process.  Execute the shell command. */
        execl (SHELL, SHELL, "-c", command, NULL);
        _exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)
    {
        /* The fork failed.  Report failure.  */
        status = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* This is the parent process.  Wait for the child to complete.  */
        if (waitpid (pid, &status, 0) != pid)
            status = -1;
    }
    return status;
}
void main()
{
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "/usr/local/bin/node &");
    nodeCmd(command);
}
```

*

Comment: You can’t determine the PID of the process started by `system()` let alone any processes it starts. If you need to know, don’t use `system()`.

Comment: any other easy way other than scanning the entire proc file system

Comment: Even scanning `/proc` won’t reliably tell you. As I said, if you need to know, don’t use `system()`.  It might be feasible using an elaborate shell script that writes the background PID on standard output that you then read, but if the program you run daemonizes itself, you’re still hosed, probably — though that likely applies to a self-daemonizing program even if you do lots of work. It depends on what you know about the program being run. And self-daemonizing programs aren’t all that common.

Comment: Scanning /proc for command line or exe name could be sufficient in your case, though it is not really reliable, and /proc  is not guaranteed to be mounted. The best way is if your program can provide some type of a dedicated registration in the file system, which yo can check.

Comment: Use `fork()` then `execvp()` for better control of child process. Don't use `system()`.

Comment: You ask for `system()` but your example does not use `system()` at all, it's using `fork()`+`execl()`.

Comment: yes, I couldn't figure out using system() so I have used popen instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running this function periodically to check whether the process is running or not. Here is my function that will check the running process in linux, C.

```
static int CheckRunningStatus(void)
    {
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        char nodePidCheck[16];
        int ret = 0;

        memset(nodePid,0,16);

        /* Open the command for reading. */
        fp = popen("pidof node", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to run command\n" );
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Read the output a line at a time - pid of node will be just 1 line*/
        // if there is no PID then nothing will be poplated inside nodePid
        fgets(nodePid, sizeof(nodePid)-1, fp);

        // check if we have got a PID value of node or not
        if(nodePid[0] == 0)
        {
            printf("node is not running!!!!\n");
            ret = -1;
        }

        /* close the popen handle */
        pclose(fp);

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: What if there's other process named `node` running in system?